# Strange static string constant behaviour in swift

Tags: swift, string

I'm declaring two strings

```
public static let FILTER_PERIODS_KEY = "fi_pe"
public static let FILTER_PERIODS_DEFAULT = "M1,M5,M15,M30,H1,H4,D1"
```

and use them that way:

```
if (preferences.object(forKey: InAppProperties.FILTER_PERIODS_KEY) == nil) {
        preferences.set(InAppProperties.FILTER_PERIODS_DEFAULT, forKey: InAppProperties.FILTER_PERIODS_KEY)
    }
```

For some reason FILTER_PERIODS_KEY is not empty, while FILTER_PERIODS_DEFAULT is empty.

What is this?

Comment: How did you find out that's empty? Does it appear empty when you put a breakpoint? Also, if `preferences` is a wrapper around `UserDefaults`, you could just use `registerDefaults` which basically does what you are doing manually here (sets a default value if none set)

Comment: At breakpoint they are empty (they, because there are many same strings)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct: `FILTER_PERIODS_DEFAULT` is used as **value** and `FILTER_PERIODS_KEY` is used as **key**.

However your way to define default values for `UserDefaults` is wrong.

As soon as possible (in `awakeFromNib` or `applicationWillFinishLaunching`) add

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let defaultValues = [InAppProperties.FILTER_PERIODS_KEY: "M1,M5,M15,M30,H1,H4,D1"]
defaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)
```

The code has to be executed every time the application launches even if the value has changed meanwhile.

Comment: but why such behaviour appears here?
It can be any class, and some static variables initiated, some are not.
It's very strange

Comment: Please note the difference between key and value